# How to add google analytics to vaadin application?

Tags: google-analytics, vaadin-flow

I'm using Vaadin 12, with spring boot. I want to add google analytics on my page.
The code looks like this:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=my-id"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'my-id');
</script>
```

How can I add this to the Vaadin's webpage?
I already tryied to use annotation @Inline, but it always put some additional stuff there. So is there a way how to put those scripts to the head of html?
I'm using only java classes without HTML pages.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually working add-on for adding Google analytics with new Vaadin 10+ projects, which adds the tracker and gives some other additional API for advanced use of the Google Analytics. You can find it from Vaadin Directory

https://vaadin.com/directory/component/googleanalyticstracker/4.0.0

(There exists similar add-on for Vaadin 7 & 8) as well.

Vaadin applications are single page, so to get full benefit of Google Analytics for behavioral tracking of the application use, you need this kind of add-on. It makes possible to have virtual page views, i.e. you can see view level activity in Google Analytics.

For simple integration of the JavaScript in head of html you can use e.g. @Inline annotation, like described here: https://vaadin.com/docs/flow/advanced/tutorial-bootstrap.html However that will not give you view level tracking.

Comment: Actually this will not help me. I really need to put those scripts to head of html.
Besides, it is mentioned on that repo that it is only for vaadin versions 6, 7 and 8